# Condense consecutive Date Range by removing overlapping rows

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Customer Membership Record sets as shown below.

```
        CustomerId | EffectiveDate | EndDate | RecordNo
        A1 | 01 - 01 - 2016 | 31 - 05 - 2016 | 1
        A1 | 01 - 06 - 2016 | 31 - 10 - 2016 | 2
        A1 | 01 - 09 - 2016 | 31 - 12 - 2017 | 3
        A1 | 02 - 11 - 2016 | 31 - 12 - 2016 | 4
        A2 | 02 - 11 - 2016 | 31 - 12 - 2016 | 5
```

The requirement is

- consecutive dates need to be combined into 1 date range
- If there is an overlapping of dates for a given Customer ID, the row should be removed

Hence my result set should look like this

```
            CustomerId | EffectiveDate | EndDate | IsBad
            A1 | 01 - 01 - 2016 | 31 - 10 - 2016 | false
            A1 | 01 - 09 - 2016 | 31 - 12 - 2017 | true
            A1 | 02 - 11 - 2016 | 31 - 12 - 2016 | false
            A2 | 02 - 11 - 2016 | 31 - 12 - 2016 | false
```

That is for the Customer A1, 1 overlapping row was set to rejected(IsBad property is set to true).
2 rows adjacent to each other were combined into 1 date range.
But record number 4 was retained as-is since they was a one day gap(it was not consecutive)

The data is stored in a `List<CustomerMembership>()` where  the `CustomerMembership` class has `CustomerId`,`EffectiveDate`,`EndDate` and `IsBad` properties.

Edit- THe question is how can I get the desired output(2nd set of data) given the input (1st set of data)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Try following :                       var join = from effdate in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       join enddate in dt.AsEnumerable() on effdate.Field<DateTime>("EndDate").AddDays(1) equals enddate.Field<DateTime>("EffectiveDate")
                       select new { effdate = effdate, enddate = enddate };

Comment: The question in from the List1, I need to derive List2. List1 and List2 are the record sets I have given respectively

Comment: Is it possible for more than 2 consecutive records to need to be combined?

Comment: Why doesn't record 4 overlap record 3?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming record 4 doesn't overlap record 3 because record 3 is marked as bad, and assuming at most two records can be combined into one record, these queries will combine the two records and then the `for` loop is the most efficient way to find the bad records. It could be done with LINQ, but it would involve multiple passes over data for little gain.

```
// find records that extend an earlier record
var step0 = from r1 in src
            join r2 in src.Skip(1) on new { r1.CustomerId, TestDate = r1.EndDateTime.AddDays(1) } equals new { r2.CustomerId, TestDate = r2.EffectiveDateTime }
            select new { r1, r2 };

// combine extended records and passthru non-extended records
var step1 = (from r1 in src
            where !step0.Any(r1r2 => r1 == r1r2.r1)
            join r1r2 in step0 on r1 equals r1r2.r1 into r1r2j
            from r1r2 in r1r2j.DefaultIfEmpty()
            let r2 = r1r2?.r2
            orderby r1.CustomerId, r1.EffectiveDateTime
            select new CustomerMembership { CustomerId = r1.CustomerId, EffectiveDateTime = r1.EffectiveDateTime, EndDateTime = (r2 != null) ? r2.EndDateTime : r1.EndDateTime }).ToArray();

// find bad records by comparing records to previous record
for (var j1 = 1; j1 < step1.Length; ++j1)
    if (!step1[j1-1].IsBad)
        step1[j1].IsBad = step1[j1].CustomerId == step1[j1-1].CustomerId &&
            (step1[j1].EffectiveDateTime.IsBetween(step1[j1-1].EffectiveDateTime, step1[j1-1].EndDateTime) ||
            step1[j1].EndDateTime.IsBetween(step1[j1-1].EffectiveDateTime, step1[j1-1].EndDateTime));

var ans = step1.ToList();
```